# breadcrumb not showing proper page structure

Tags: breadcrumb

problem is just the subpages do not show their parents...else is working absolutely fine

```
  function the_breadcrumb() {

   $sep = ' » ';

   if (!is_front_page()) {

    echo '<div class="breadcrumbs">';
    echo '<a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo '</a>' . $sep;

    if (is_category() || is_single() ){
       the_category('title_li=');
    } elseif (is_archive() || is_single()){
        if ( is_day() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date() );
        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            printf( __( '%s', 'text_domain' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'text_domain' ) ) );
        } else {
            _e( 'Blog Archives', 'text_domain' );
        }
      }

      if (is_single()) {
        echo $sep;
        the_title();
      }

      if (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
     }

      if (is_home()){
        global $post;
        $page_for_posts_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
        if ( $page_for_posts_id ) { 
            $post = get_page($page_for_posts_id);
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_title();
            rewind_posts();
          }
        }

      echo '</div>';
     }
    }
```

Comment: Inside your `is_page()` condition, check if the current page has parent (`$post->post_parent`), then if it has, get the parent page title from the parent page id and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working as @Pieter suggested to check if page has parent or not.

Got the help from here 
 [Breadcrumb how i can display page title with parent > child title with permalink ? any Idea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123130/breadcrumb-how-i-can-display-page-title-with-parent-child-title-with-permalink)